# Help wiring relay to LED driver - L/N on driver to L/O on relay?

Tags: led, relay

I have a [Shelly Dimmer 2](https://shelly.cloud/knowledge-base/devices/shelly-dimmer-2/) wifi-controlled relay, and I'm a bit confused as to wiring it to my LED module. The front of the relay looks like this:

[image: Shelly Dimmer 2 wiring]

This is the LED lamp I am trying to connect. At one end is a normal 2-prong 240V mains plug (i.e. AU plug, no earth), it goes to a LED driver, then to the LED module itself:

[image]

Closeup of the LED driver

[image]

There is a "L" and a "N' on the left input side.

I'm just trying to understand the correct way to wire it up to the relay.

Should I connect "L" on the driver to "L" on the relay? And then "N" on the driver to "O" on the relay?

Or is there another way to do this?

I don't need a physical switch in my case, I just need to use wifi to control the relay to control the LED.

(Shelly also talks about using a https://shop.shelly.cloud/bypass-wifi-smart-home-automation if you don't have a neutral, and your load is < 10W. I assume the LED draws very little at idle, so that my be needed here).

Comment: I must know; what is the keyboard partially pictured in the top of your first photo?

Comment: @Hitek It's a bit like one of [these](https://github.com/ecopoesis/nek-type-a)

Comment: @Finbarr - That is pretty neat, but that is a split keyboard, and the one in the photo is some sort of laptop-like mini consolidated keyboard.  Any one else(or the original poster) know what this keyboard might be?  Sorry in advance for asking non-question related inquiries!

Comment: The keyboard is a Keychron K6 mechanical bluetooth keyboard, with the Granite keyset (in "blank" configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual you linked to:

> When using the device without neutral, Shelly Dimmer 2
> requires at least 10W of power consumption, in order to operate. If the connected light has a smaller power consumption, then Shelly Bypass is required for the operation of the Device.

So as (or if) you think your LED array is going to draw less than 10W, you should wire it with a neutral if you can otherwise you'll need to add their bypass device. The option to wire without a neutral is really for retrofitting this device to a house where neutrals often aren't run to the switches because they don't need to be with conventional wiring.

In addition, wiring it WITH a neutral will allow you to operate the wi-fi functions without any load connected, or if the load should fail at some future point. Without a neutral, the dimmer always requires some current flowing through the load in order for its internal electronics to run.

Wire it in accordance with the manual, with L of your driver to O and the neutrals connected together:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused.

In my case, the LED driver has "L" and "N" - that means it has a neutral right?

So would I be OK simply connecting "L" from the LED driver to one of the "L" terminals on the relay, and the "N" from the LED driver to "O on the relay?

Comment: Your driver is represented by the little white circle with a cross in. The L terminal of the driver goes to the O terminal of the relay and the N terminal of the driver goes to the N terminal of the relay along with the supply N.

Comment: Thanks - can confirm I was able to get this working. Photo of my final layout - https://i.imgur.com/SfzvBQt.jpg - and then used a screw terminal to wire the three neutrals together - https://i.imgur.com/eguL8Gp.jpg.

Comment: @user37872 Glad to hear it, please accept the answer by way of thanks as it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to manual, bypass required then is no neutral. It is the wiring then the device installed in switch box. Sometimes switch box does not have neutral wire. Installing in lighting fixture or connection box bypass not needed. Apply fig.1 from manual. Power line connect to L of switch, O connect with L of LED power supply. All neutrals connect together,N of power, N of switch and N of LED PS. Device designed to use with in-wall wiqeiring. If  intend to use it with cord and plug, make sure the plug is polarized. Do not mix between neutral and phase